# Explanation of the output of timeit in the CLI

Tags: python, time

In the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#examples) of `timeit` module, I couldn't find a detailed explanation of the output of `timeit.timeit` when it is run from the command line:

```
>python -m timeit "sum(range(5))"
500000 loops, best of 5: 521 nsec per loop
```

In the example above, I understand that it executes the statement 500000 times. But I have no idea why it says best of 5 instead of best of 500000.

Could you please explain what is the meaning of "best of 5"? why not "best of 500000"?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: best of 5 means it's performing the benchmark 5 times and taking the best time of those 5. this minimizes errors due to background processes etc

Comment: @BlueLightning42: Could you give more details please, does that mean it executes the statement for `500000*5 = 2500000` times?

Comment: yes https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface if you check the documentation for the command-line interface you can see using the -r option changes the amount of repetitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Timeit module document:

> default_timer() measurements can be affected by other programs running on the same machine, so the best thing to do when accurate timing is necessary is to repeat the timing a few times and use the best time. The -r option is good for this; the default of 5 repetitions is probably enough in most cases. You can use time.process_time() to measure CPU time.

```sh
yihaos-mbp:~ yihao$ python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.3 usec per loop
yihaos-mbp:~ yihao$ python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.2 usec per loop
yihaos-mbp:~ yihao$ python3 -m timeit -r 1 '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 1: 21.9 usec per loop
yihaos-mbp:~ yihao$ python3 -m timeit -r 100 '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
10000 loops, best of 100: 21.6 usec per loop
```

You see everytime you execute timeit, the timing can be different, this is due to other processes going on, so the larger your repetition is the more accurate it gets.

Hope that explains your concern, please accept answer and vote.

Comment: I couldn't understand, does that mean it execute the statement `500000 * 5 = 2500000` times?

Comment: Yes, by default -r = 5. The timer executes your 50000 loops five times and takes the average to make sure it's more accurate. @IamNotaMathematician

Comment: Could you please give a very basic example?

Comment: @IamNotaMathematician Added above.